# Why is plot put before kable in pdf using RMarkdown

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, kable

Using the following code, I get a pdf with the plot in desired place.

````
---
title: "Stackquestion"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
```

## R Markdown

Whatever text

```{r cars}
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kbl(dt, booktabs = T)

```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

[image: Right placement]

But when adding `kable_styling` the plot is placed in wrong position. Is there a way to get around this?

````
---
title: "Stackquestion"
author: "Author"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
```

## R Markdown

Whatever text

```{r cars}
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kbl(dt, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  add_header_above(c("Some text also goes here"))

```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
````

[image: Wrong placement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `latex_options` in `kable_styling`:

```
kable_styling(full_width = F, latex_options = "HOLD_position")
```